# Auto Return Not Working In PayPal Pro Hosted Solution?

Tags: paypal

I am using the new PayPal Pro Hosted Solution on a new site, and all seems to work 'OK' apart from auto return does not work?

I have auto return enabled in my paypal account along with IPN and payment data as I have the auto return working with normal Paypal on my old site (*So I know its setup correctly*). And I have all the correct fields INCLUDING the '**return**' variable set and sent to PayPal on this pro-hosted form.

After successful payment I just get the standard Paypal pro hosted thank you page (*There is no delay redirect, I left it on the page for over a minute*)??? There is a return link on the page, which if pressed returns me to the correct page.

**BUT I need the users auto returned**? Or this solution is useless to me as I won't be able to track conversions? I can't be the only person needing this surely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this. it IS possible with credit cards and PayPal. Just make sure you add the following variables

**return** with your return url in it
**showHostedThankyouPage** with a value of false

Comment: Struggling since 2 days. PayPal doc SUCKS
You saved my Day :-)

Comment: Same here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Was the buyer paying with their PayPal account or credit card.  With Auto Return, the buyer is automatically returned when the buyer pays with their PayPal account, however if the buyer pays with their credit card they are not automatically redirected.  They are given time to write the information down or print the page.  Unlike someone that pays with their PayPal account, they can not always get back to the transaction details.  The buyer that pays with a credit card will have to click the link to return back to the merchants site.  This is why it is better to rely on IPN than auto return.  IPN will take place regardless if the buyer returns to your site.

Comment: Sorry but that is crazy. This is an unusable solution then for most large ecommerce stores. How are we supposed to track conversions if the user doesn't get auto returned? People are spending £1000's on PPC they are not going to use this solution unless its trackable. ALSO Why is this not in the documentation.... I would never have started developing a solution with it if I had known this from the outset.